# how to run mongo export on macbook?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am using mongodb Atlas (M0), which does not provide db backup feature. I am creating a nodejs script that will export all the collections automatically periodically.

So far I have done the following:

- created a programmatic api from my login.
- whitelisted my ip
- installed mongocli
- created a default profile using public and private api keys.

And command looks like this:

`mongoexport --uri mongodb+srv://${mongoUser}:${mongoPass}@mongoprojectname.lok0l.mongodb.net/${database} --collection ${collection} --type ${fileType} --out ${fileName} --profile default`

I am not able to figure out how to run this command. If I run this command in my terminal I get this error:
/bin/sh: mongoexport: command not found\n

Answer (score 0):

You have to import MongoDB tools [via](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools?tck=docs_databasetools) .

Download, unzip, and use the export path and run the command below on the terminal and try the export command again.

```
export PATH=$PATH:inputmongodbtoolpath
```

If you already use brew, you can try with it.

```
brew install mongodb-community
brew services start mongodb-community
```

Comment: As of MongoDB v4.4, mongoexport is part of the database tools and is installed separately. See Installing Database Tools. [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/installation/installation-macos/#installing-the-database-tools-on-macos)

Comment: no need to install MongoDB-community if using an atlas. Installing mongocli and database tools worked fine. Originally I installed the mongocli but somehow missed database tools. But now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

For running mongoexport command you need to install database tools separately.
Once you install mongocli and database tools then mongoexport runs from the terminal just like any other command.

I did the following to run the mongoexport. some of it might be unnecessary but worked for me:)

- installed mongocli
- created api key for the project
- whitelisted my ip in the mongo settings
- installed database tools from the mongo website
- created a default profile using mongocli config command

[This is the link to mongo database tools](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/installation/installation-macos/#installing-the-database-tools-on-macos)